# Action<T> vs delegate event

Tags: c#, delegates

I have seen developers using the below codes quite alternatively. What is the exact difference between these, and which ones go by the standard? Are they same, as `Action` and `Func<T>` is a delegate as well:

```
public event Action<EmployeeEventAgs> OnLeave;
public void Leave()
{
    OnLeave(new EmployeeEventAgs(this.ID));
}
```

VS

```
public delegate void GoOnLeave(EmployeeEventAgs e);
public event GoOnLeave OnLeave;
public void Leave()
{
    OnLeave(new EmployeeEventAgs(this.ID));
}
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Fwiw, neither example uses standard .NET conventions.  The `EventHandler<T>` generic should declare the event:

```
public event EventHandler<EmployeeEventArgs> Leave;
```

The "On" prefix should be reserved for a protected method that raises the event:

```
protected virtual void OnLeave(EmployeeEventArgs e) {
    var handler = Leave;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
}
```

You don't *have* to do it this way, but anybody will instantly recognize the pattern, understand your code and know how to use and customize it.

And it has the great advantage of not being forced to choose between a custom delegate declaration and `Action<>`, `EventHandler<>` is the best way.  Which answers your question.

Comment: This is fine advice, but I don't think it answers the question

Comment: Did you declare the `Leave` handler as a delegate, instead of: public __event__ EventHandler<> ... on purpose? The `event` keyword is quite a game changer when you work with the class exposing the event, as without it one could simply wipe out the entire event collection by using `obj.Leave = someHandler` instead of `obj.Leave += someHandler`

Comment: No, that was a mistake.  Nobody noticed in three years :) Thanks!

Answer (score 40):

The following two lines of code are almost equivalent:

```
public event Action<EmployeeEventAgs> Leave;
```

compared to:

```
public event EventHandler<EmployeeEventAgs> Leave;
```

The difference is in the signature of the event handler method. If you use the first approach with the action, you could have:

```
public void LeaveHandler(EmployeeEventAgs e) { ... }
```

and then this:

```
obj.Leave += LeaveHandler;
```

With the second approach, the signature of the `LeaveHandler` needs to be different:

```
public void LeaveHandler(object sender, EmployeeEventAgs e) { ... }
```

---

It is *very important* to notice that in both cases the `event` keyword is used to declare the event member. An event member declared this way is not simply a field of the class, despite it looks as if it was. Instead, the compiler creates it as an **event property**<sup>1</sup>. The event properties are similar to regular properties, except that they do not have `get` or `set` accessors. The compiler allows them to be used only on the left side of a `+=` and `-=` assignments (adding or removing an event handler). There is no way to *overwrite the already assigned event handlers*, or to *invoke the event outside the class that declares* it.

If the event keyword was missing in both examples, you could do the following operations with no error or warning:

```
obj.Leave = LeaveHandler;
```

which will **erase any registered handlers** and replace them withe the `LeaveHandler`.

In addition, you can also perform this call:

```
obj.Leave(new EmployeeEventAgs());
```

The two situations above are considered an *anti-pattern*, if you intend to create an event. An event should be invoked *only by the owner object* and should not allow for *untraceable* removal of subscribers. The `event` keyword is the .NET's programmatic construct that helps you stick with the correct use of events.

Having the above in mind, I believe many people stick to the `EventHandler` approach because it is more unlikely to use an `EventHandler` without the `event` keyword. Actions have wider scope of usage, they do not look as naturally when used as events. The latter is, of course, a personal opinion, as the event handler approach has probably become too hardwired in my own coding practices. Still, if actions are used properly, it is not a crime to use them for events.

---

<sup>1</sup> An event property is what the compiler automatically generates when seeing code like this:

```
event EventHandler SomeEvent
```

It becomes roughly the same code as the following:

```
private EventHandler _someEvent; // notice the lack of the event keyword!
public event EventHandler SomeEvent
{
    add { _someEvent += value; }
    remove { _someEvent -= value; }
}
```

Event invocations which we write as this:

```
this.SomeEvent(sender, args);
```

are converted into this:

```
this._someEvent(sender, args);
```

Answer (score 26):

`Action<T>` is exactly the same as `delegate void ... (T t)`

`Func<T>` is exactly the same as `delegate T ... ()`

Comment: Not *exactly the same*... they do have the same signature, but they're not assignment compatible (which IMHO is very unfortunate...)

Comment: Does that make them not exactly the same? Are X and Y different here:

        public delegate void X<T>(T t);
        public delegate void Y<T>(T t);

You cannot assign one to another.

Answer (score 9):

Action is just a shortcut for the full delegate declaration.

```
public delegate void Action<T>(T obj)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx

Which one to use would depend on your organizations coding standards/style.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Action and Func are simply convenience delegates that have been defined in the 3.5 clr.

Action, Func and lambdas are all just syntactical sugar and convenience for using delegates.

There is nothing magic about them. Several people have written simple 2.0 addon libraries to add this functionality to 2.0 code.

Answer (score 5):

**[You may want to look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276962/c-delegates-reference-resolution-time)**, seeing what the compiler actually generates for Action is the best description.  There's no functional difference in what you wrote, just shorter, more convenient syntax.

Answer (score 3):

In general, they are equivalent. But in the context of using a delegate for the type of an event, the convention is to use EventHandler (where T inherits EventArgs):

```
public event EventHandler<EmployeeEventArgs> Left;

public void Leave()
{
    OnLeft(this.ID);
}

protected virtual void OnLeft(int id)
{
    if (Left != null) {
        Left(new EmployeeEventArgs(id));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have written these Action and Func generic delegates yourself, but since they're generally useful they wrote them for you and stuck them in .Net libraries.