# Event handler raising method convention

Tags: c#, coding-style, delegates

I was just browsing and came across this question:

[Action vs delegate event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282476/actiont-vs-delegate-event)

[The answer from nobug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282476/actiont-vs-delegate-event/2282683#2282683) included this code:

```
protected virtual void OnLeave(EmployeeEventArgs e) {
  var handler = Leave;
  if (handler != null)
    handler(this, e);
}
```

Resharper also generates similar code when using the "create raising method" quick-fix.

My question is, why is this line necessary?:

```
var handler = Leave;
```

Why is it better than writing this?:

```
protected virtual void OnLeave(EmployeeEventArgs e) {
  if (Leave != null)
    Leave(this, e);
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's better because there is a tiny possibility that `Leave` becomes null after the null check, but before the invocation (which would cause your code to throw a `NullReferenceException`). Since the delegate type is immutable, if you first assign it to a variable this possibility goes away; your local copy will not be affected by any changes to `Leave` after the assignment.

Note though that this approach also creates a issue in reverse; it means that there is a (tiny, but existing) possibility that an event handler gets invoked *after it has been detached from the event*. This scenario should of course be handled gracefully as well.

Answer (score 5):

In a multi-threaded application, you could get a null reference exception if the caller unregisters from the event. The assignment to a local variable protects against this.

Odds are you'd never see this (until it hurts you the worst). Here's a way of looking at it that shows the problem...

```
protected virtual void OnLeave(EmployeeEventArgs e) {
  if (Leave != null) //subscriber is registered to the event
  {
    //Subscriber unregisters from event....
    Leave(this, e); //NullReferenceException!
  }
}
```

Comment: Yup.  Getting the event handler called after unregistering it is an unfixable race.  The NRE is easily fixable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an excellent explanation by Eric Lippert :

[Events and races](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/29/events-and-races.aspx)